# ASP.NET Parser Error:Could not load type (LINE 1)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm a newb to ASP.NET and I made an app in **VS2010 using NET 4.0** (Working all fine in debug mode)
I tried to host my app @ aspspider and I'm getting the following error:

```
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'AuthStealerPanel._Default'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="AuthStealerPanel._Default" %>
```

I also tried to rebuild the .dll and upload it to the /bin/ and application's root.
Any help? :>

Answer (score 1):

When you make any changes in **page-behind code** file then you also have to **upload the .aspx** file and if your project **have User Controls** then upload **Masterpage** and **UserControls** files also

Comment: by **.aspx** means the related **.aspx** file only

Comment: I published with VS Studio. 
It generated a folder with all my aspx files and a /bin/ with 3 files and /scripts/ with 3 files.

Should I upload aspx.vb to?

Comment: Can you please tell what folder have you uploaded... because i think either you have not properly uploaded the bin folder or the aspx files

Comment: I published it to c:\Application and then uploaded this folder.

Comment: ok i quit here is the ultimate link 'http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=553&q=Description%3A+An+error+occurred+during+the+parsing+of+a+resource+required+to+service+this+request.+Please+review+the+following+specific+parse+error+details+and+modify+your+source+file+appropriately.&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&fp=ad69f97b3d463bae'

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this error, then you haven't set up your site in IIS yet.  IIS is short for "*Internet Information Services*" and it's basically your webserver for .net web apps, like Apache would be for php.  Every hosting provider is different, but you will always have a folder you publish your website to.  You have to configure IIS to recognize this folder as a virtual directory and allow your applications to run in there.

For example:

With GoDaddy, you have to go to "*IIS Managment*", click "*Create*" to create the virtual directory in IIS (doesn't matter if the directory already exists in the folder structure), and check the box that says "*Set Application Root*" - this tells IIS you'll be running asp.net code in there.

With DiscountAsp.net you would go to the "*Web Application Tool*", select the folder you've published to and click on "*Install Application*".  This will associate the directory with a new virtual directory in IIS and set it up to run asp.net code.

I haven't used other hosting providers, so these two are all I know.