# Publishing .Net 4.0 application error at runtime

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, web-hosting, publishing

I hope this is ok asking here..
I Have been making an asp.net application I have the following in my Solution:

- Business Class (.net Class Library)
- DataAccess Class(.net Class Library)
- Web Application

So when I go to Build>Publish Web, it publishes successfully. So then I go to upload via ftp to my Godaddy hosting account, and I get a runtime error.  I am going crazy because if I open the published files on my local machine everything works fine! can anyone help me with this?

here is the [link](http://condominiosurconuevo.com/triveno/login.aspx) to my web.

If this is not a valid question here I'll take it down but I am desperate.  Thanks

ps. I set godaddy hosting programming language to framework 4.0

Edit: I figured out how to show the error but it's strange

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="web.login" %>

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'web.login'.
```

now in that page the I have to use that because in my codebehind it has:

```
namespace web
{
   public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
```

and that namespace is used in the designer.aspx.cs aswell..

im stumped :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the help but the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6653654/933552) did it.  In godaddy you have to setup in their IIS Management a Virtual Application

"With GoDaddy, you have to go to "IIS Managment", click "Create" to create the virtual directory in IIS (doesn't matter if the directory already exists in the folder structure), and check the box that says "Set Application Root" - this tells IIS you'll be running asp.net code in there."

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to start from what the error is saying:

> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on
>   remote machines, please create a  tag within a
>   "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This  tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Doing so will let you see what's the real error. And then to fix it :)

Comment: you would recieve such an error if the application is not build. You should build it somehow and have all the dlls in bin.

Comment: i did that, I've built and rebuilt, published and copied all files in the publish folder created.  Should I not use the publish and just copy files in my web folder? When I go to the project dependencies I can't add that web.dll as reference cause its the same web application